# In TabBarController "More" tabs comes out in landscape mode on iphone 6+ IOS 8.3

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, landscape, iphone-6-plus, ios8.3

In my application i am using tab bar controller , I have 10 tabs in TabBar Controller and in portrait mode only 4 tabs are visible on screen and remaining 6 tabs are hidden in "More" tab.

The Problem is on Iphone6+(8.3) when i rotate the phone in landscape, the tabs that were hidden in "More" tab comes out and are visible on screen, in such a way that 7 tabs are visible on screen and remaining 3 are hidden in "More" tab.

Now i want some help so that when i rotate the phone to landscape, only 4 tabs remain on screen (as in portrait mode) and other 6 tabs remain hidden in "More" tab.

This problem is only occuring on iphone 6+ that have IOS 8.3, on other iphones including iphone6+ (IOS less then 8.3), 4 tabs are visible on screen and the other 6 tabs remain hidden in "More" tab in portrait and landscape mode. One more thing if i remove the launch images for iphone6 and iphone6+ then again every thing is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may override the default behaviour of the `UITabBarController` by setting the property `@property(nonatomic,copy)   NSArray             *items;        // get/set visible UITabBarItems. default is nil. changes not animated. shown in order`

You can also customise the default layout :

```
/*
 Default is UITabBarItemPositioningAutomatic. The tab bar items fill horizontally
 for the iPhone user interface idiom, and are centered with a default width and 
 inter-item spacing (customizable with the itemWidth and itemSpacing
 properties) for the iPad idiom. When the tab bar is owned by a UITabBarController
 further heuristics may determine the positioning for UITabBarItemPositioningAutomatic.
    Use UITabBarItemPositioningFill to force the items to fill horizontally.
    Use UITabBarItemPositioningCenter to force the items to center with a default
 width (or the itemWidth, if set).
 */
@property(nonatomic) UITabBarItemPositioning itemPositioning NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

/*
 Set the itemWidth to a positive value to be used as the width for tab bar items
 when they are positioned as a centered group (as opposed to filling the tab bar).
 Default of 0 or values less than 0 will be interpreted as a system-defined width.
 */
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat itemWidth NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

/*
 Set the itemSpacing to a positive value to be used between tab bar items
 when they are positioned as a centered group.
 Default of 0 or values less than 0 will be interpreted as a system-defined spacing.
 */
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat itemSpacing NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```